Where on Earth do tides go out furthest?
Many sources state that the Bay of Fundy has the largest vertical tidal range. The horizontal range is also very large (up to 5 km according to this website: https://fundyforce.ca/learning-portal/tides). Is this the largest horizontal tidal range in the world?

The Wadden Sea in the German Bight of the North Sea from Danmark in the North to the Netherlands in the South-West has probably the largest horizontal range of the tides by quite some margin; The tidal area is there up to 20 ... 40km wide (depending on how you measure):

Wikipedia has a list of tidal flats, and there are other significant ones, but they seem to be slightly-steeper-sloped so that they are often not as wide.
